# Metadata in a Stream

Tags: apache, metadata, mime-types, apache-tika

I have a requirement such that I have to extract the metadata and detect Mime type from a file stream. How can I do it with minimum amount of bytes of the stream?

Comment: Apache Tika can detect most non-container types with just the first few hundred bytes of the file. However, to get the metadata you *must* give Tika the whole file!